# Div disappears when no control is in it

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have a `div` that keeps disappearing. If I put a control in it it is fine. I need something clickable that does not make a postback so I can run a `jQuery` function that toggles a `div` into view. If a postback occurs I see the slider function revert. An `<a/>` element works but I would like a pic instead. How can I make this `div` show up?

```
<div id="wrapper" class="m_div" style="height:30px">
<div style="height:30px;width:30px;min-height:30px;min-width:30px;background:url('/Styles/Menu.png')" ><a href="#" id="click">   </a> </div>
 <div id="slider" runat="server">
  //menu controls are here
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  >
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
      $("#slider").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left",
        distance: 280
      }, 500);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what do you need that empty div for?

Comment: To hold something clickable as far as jQuery

Comment: You could as well use a `<button>` / `<input type="button">`. See my answer on that ;)

Comment: maybe i didn't understand this right. you want to hide m_div when image is clicked, then? i mean, how do you want to show it back after that "since u said toggle"? maybe a link that says show/hide image?

Comment: The `div` I am toggling is not even in the elements I showed you. That parts works as long as I use <a/> tags

Comment: remove "display:block" from the second div, and put "display:none" on the first div instead.

Comment: could help better if provided with a sample of the whole pieces together maybe. can paste somewhere?

Comment: which div keeps disappearing? also, <a href="#" id="click"></a> doesn't have anything inside?

Comment: Well now even when I put text in <a/> it still is allowing that parent `div` disappear. The second `div` is the one that i cannot keep from disappearing.

Comment: from the code given, i can't see anything that's hiding that div. anyways, u can still "display:block !important" on that div, or maybe move it outside m_div

Comment: pleas, just provide the erroneous code somwhere we can acutally see it in action. if there is non-whitespace content inside that `a`,  there sin'T a single reason why that div should not show up.

Comment: I have it working now, it must have been a bad link to the css file - which does not make sense - as the form was showing some of the properties that were only available from the css file. There must be some bug in my VS designer which is horribly off from production anyway, but to show me it is connected to the css file when it really is not - is totally unacceptable, but what can I do - it's not my UI designer its Microsoft's POS.

Comment: Do you think they could at least offer us which web engine we would like it to render as the designer within VS - no of course not that would make too much sense. Thanks for your help. I don't know how to award any of the answers since they did not fix it. I don't see how anyone could have seen this - including myself. Just glad everyone has a point for there trouble.

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements always have the smallest size that it needs to fit vontents. If they have no contents, they "disappear". Use CSS to set a (minimal) width - that shoudl work, if it doesn't, you're doing something else wrong.

Not sure why you need the div though. YOu can get click events on any HTML element, if if those elements have default actions, you can always cancel them by calling `.preventDefault()` on the event.

Comment: min-width and min-height are not working. I do have some content in it - it's an <a/> element

Answer (score 1):

Add the `HTML` code for a non-breaking space: `&nbsp;` as this will give you an "empty" div with minimal impact on the layout:

```
<div class="m_div" style="height:30px">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="m_div" style="height:30px;display:block;">
<div style="height:30px;width:30px;background:url('/Styles/Menu.png')" >&nbsp;</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
<a id="click" style="display: inline-block; height:30px; width: 30px; background:url('/Styles/Menu.png'); text-indent: -200px;" href="#">Click</a>
```

By default, an `<a>` element is an inline element. You can't specify a width or a height for an inline element. Therefore you need to change it to "inline-block". Notice how I also put the text "Click" inside the element body, but then set the "text-indent" so it doesn't show up. That's good for screen readers.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuP6z/1/)

Comment: That did not change it either. I even moved it out of the wrapper div. no change. I can see it just fine in the designer - this is getting so frustrating! Thanks for helping everyone!

Comment: I know, as long as this element does not disappear it does work.

Comment: @DonA- I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuP6z/1/) to include a call to `e.preventDefault()`. When attaching a click-handler to an `<a>` element, it is best to include that.